# Why should I "Set up my profile" within contacts?

Tags: cyanogenmod, contacts

When I go into my contacts (via the "People" application) I'm always prompted to set up my profile:

[image]

Apart from placing my personal details at the top of the contacts list in case I forget who I am, is there any other benefit to actually filling this information out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few possible uses. This special contact also sets your photo and name in the quick-settings tray (the one you pull down from the top-right), and it's the source of the name and image used if you have multiple user profiles on a tablet.

If someone finds your phone unlocked, they might use your contact details to help find you and return your phone, but the settings here don't affect the lock screen message, which is the usual way to help your phone get back to you.

You might also use this to quickly send your contact details to someone else's phone via Bluetooth or NFC.

Finally, apps which you grant the appropriate permission ("Read your contacts" and "Read your own contact card") can read this special contact. They might do this to address you by the correct name, or to set up contact data without you having to enter it again. Obviously, exactly what they do depends on the particular app. For example, I have a free app [Owner Photo Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shadowburst.showr.owner) which uses this feature to make it easy to put your photo in a lock screen widget. This makes it easy to identify whose phone it is, if you leave it behind in the office, or a similar situation.